# Messenger Chatbot: track the user's chatting history with bot while implementing human handover protocol

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Currently, I've successfully developed **Human Handover Protocol** for **Messenger Bot**.

- The user will normally interact with the bot.
- If the user click on
  "`Chat with a person`", bot will stop working and the users' input will
  be sent to the **Page Inbox**.
- After the page admin click on "`Mark as done`", the bot will take back the thread control.

It works as planned. The problem is that we also want to look and track **all the users chatting with the bot** even if he is only interacting with the bot. Because we want to track that our bot has any defects.

I know I **can record the data from my Server side**. But I'm curious is there any smarter solutions to handle that problem. May be two **inboxes**. One inbox for "**Human Handover Protocol**" and one inbox for "**All chating history**".

Answer (score 0):

Create another app, add it as Secondary Receiver and subscribe it to the standby event. It will be able to see all incoming webhook events, regardless of what app is currently chatting:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/standby